# Calculating the sum of the quantities of one table based on dates in another table in sql

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a first table like this:

tbl1:

```
 item     date1         date2
   1    2020-06-21    2020-06-28
   2    2020-05-13    2020-05-24
   3    2020-06-20    2020-06-28
```

I also have a second table with the items, a date and a quantity

tbl2:

```
 item     quantity       date
   1         5        2020-06-24
   1         8        2020-06-20
   1         12       2020-06-27
   1         9        2020-06-29
   2         10       2020-05-24
   2         11       2020-05-15
   2         18       2020-05-18
   2         9        2020-05-14
   3         7        2020-06-18
   3         12       2020-06-21
   3         13       2020-06-24
   3         8        2020-06-28
```

Now I want to sum the quantities from tbl2 where the date is between the columns date1 and date2.
So my result would look like:

tbl1:

```
 item     date1         date2        sum
   1    2020-06-21    2020-06-28     17
   2    2020-05-13    2020-05-24     48
   3    2020-06-20    2020-06-28     33
```

I've been starring at it for a while now and I really want to avoid a loop.

Is there an efficient way of obtaining the desired result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just join them, group by `table1` and sum:

```sql
select t1.*, sum(t2.quantity)
from table1 t1;
left join table2 t2 on t2.item = t1.item and
    t2.date >= t1.date1 and
    t2.date <= t1.date2
group by t1.item, t1.date1, t1.date2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery, for instance:

```
select t1.*,
       (select sum(t2.quantity)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.item = t1.item and
              t2.date >= t1.date1 and
              t2.date <= t1.date2
       ) as quantity
from table1 t1;
```

Assuming your database supports indexes, than this is probably the fastest approach with an index on `table2(item, date, quantity)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
      SELECT C.ITEM,C.DATE1,C.DATE2,SUM(C2.QUANTITY)S
      FROM tbl1 AS C
      LEFT JOIN tbl2 AS C2 ON C.ITEM=C2.ITEM AND C2.DATE BETWEEN C.DATE1 AND C.DATE2
      GROUP BY C.ITEM,C.DATE1,C.DATE2
```

You can try also this